# How to flip linux console?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, console

I want to flip the image output of the linux console when not in XServer.

I saw an issue that is similar to this here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/237963/how-do-i-rotate-my-display-when-not-using-an-x-server

The thing that changes is that I don't want to rotate the output, I need to actually vertically flip it.

If it is possible I would also like to apply it at every boot.

Comment: Like, so text is reversed, as in reading in a mirror?

Comment: Yes just like that

Answer (score 1):

> I want to flip the image output of the linux console when not in XServer.

If you follow the link to the [fbcon documentation](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt#126) in the links in your linked question, you'll find that the fbcon driver can't do that.

You're basically out of luck. You could extend what is done in the fbdev/core/fbcon_rotate.c system to also make it possible to mirror the output, but that would require you to become a Linux developer.